# Validation for textarea in reactjs

Tags: jquery, validation, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am new to react and redux, currently working on validation of fields. I am able to validate `<Field type="text" component="input" />` type fields. But how to validate `selectbox`, `textarea` and `radio` buttons.

Below is my code for validation for `<Field type="text" component="input" />`

```
const required = value => value ? undefined : 'Required'

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type}/>
      {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
    </div>
  </div>
)

class myApp extends React.Component {

render() {

return (
<div>
<Field type="text" component={renderField} validate={required} />
</div>

)
}
}
```

Please help,

Thanks much, 
Shash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not utilizing react in the way it was intended. Validation should be happening on your state primarily. You may validate your fields but this is more for the user than it is for you.

Inputs should simply take a property from state as the `value` and their `onChange` method should update the state. All input types have an onChange which is how you update the state with the new value (even if its a single new letter) and because the state was updated the value the input is set to the updated value.

[Here is the link to the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)

ex:

```
<input 
....
onChange={this.onChange}
/>
```

and in your class have

```
onChange(value){
   this.setState({inputValue: value});
}
```

Then if you want to validate a required field simply validate your state:

```
//this is an example function you can call when the save button is clicked
onSave(){
    if(this.props.isRequired && this.state.value == ''){
       alert('The input '+this.state.label+' requires a value';);
    }
}
```

Now if you want to show pretty validation messages if lets say the user clicks save and there are parts of the state that are not filled out correctly I would recommend either creating your own code that changes the UI to notify the user or there are plenty of nice libraries out there.

You have imposed the form element type issue on yourself with your use of renderField. You have two options: 1- dont try rendering your own component or 2- account for the different form types (textareas, selectboxs, & inputs).

The library you are using gives you the ability to simply say `<Field type="text" component={'textarea'} validate={required} />` or `<Field type="text" component={'input'} validate={required} />`. For entry use this is the template I would recommend using. If you want to use your current system you will need to create a system for determining whether you should render an input or textarea for example:

```
const renderInputField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => (
    <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
            <div>
                <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type}/>
                {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
            </div>
    </div>
)

const renderTextareaField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => (
    <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
            <div>
                <textarea {...input} placeholder={label} type={type}/>
                {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
            </div>
    </div>
)

//in your render function simply call
<Field type="text" component={renderInputField} validate={required} />
<Field type="text" component={renderTextareaField} validate={required} />
```

Comment: Thanks, much helpful. However I am using redux-form 6.4.3, I want to validate the redux-form fields. Please suggest.

Comment: I have never used this library. From their docs it seems like you need to change your renderField function to return the right form element type. I would remove all the HTML that isn't the input and have some property that defined the type which you should render. I am not by my computer but can post an example later today

Comment: see my edits, if they don't help I would suggest re asking the question for your specific library as this answer answers the question you asked.